# WPF Application Has Lost Windows 8 Style And Reverted to a XP Like Look

Tags: c#, wpf

For no reason I can think of - there have been no code changes, My WPF application has stopped showing the window frame in the Windows 8 style and seems to have reverted to a Windows XP like style (weird grey border around the main window and grey, raised buttons for minimize,maximize and close in the top right corner.

If I try and resize the window you can see the Win8 style buttons trying to draw "underneath" before the grey button style draws over it. (that's the best I can describe it)

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Got some screenshots? What version of Windows, .NET, etc running on? Also, this is hilarious.

Comment: As I recall, window frame is rendered by OS, not by WPF.  Also, what's happening with controls inside window? Are they rendered correctly? If so, OS definitely tells WPF to use correct theme (Aero2), something is surely wrong with dwm.exe.

Comment: Don't worry, it's a phase all apps go through at some point, they go "old school" and nostalgic of the past... Sorry, just kidding. It certainly looks like a Windows OS problem, not something specific of your application. Does it happen with any other program? WPF ones specially?

Comment: Have about the rest of the desktop, is still in Aero Mode?  Also has your graphics driver crashed and restarted?  You can look in the event log for evidence of that.

Comment: Was a manifest file for the application added or removed recently? The presence (or lack) of a manifest file can cause the operating system to treat the application differently as far as rendering, control look and feel, etc.

Comment: This isn't an OS issue as all other windows are fine including a couple of other WPF applications. The manifest file has not been changed. The only thing I can see that has changed is that a strong assembly name (snk) file was added.